# Celsius/Fahrenheit conversion error

Tags: java

sorry for my beginners mistakes, but I was coding a calculator that will convert fahrenheit to celsius and celsius to fahrenheit, but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "69C"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
    at Converter.main(Converter.java:39)
```

Here is my code, hope you can help:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter!");
        System.out.println("To convert, type in your temperature and the
                            identify if you are using fahrenheit or celsius.");
        System.out.println("Example: 69F or 69C F = Fahrenheit C = Celsius");

        String temperature;
        char f = 'f';
        char c = 'c';
        double answer , temp;

        temperature = keyboard.nextLine();            

        if (temperature.contains("F")) {
            temperature = temperature.replace(f , ' ');
            temp = Double.valueOf(temperature);
            answer = temp - 30 / 2;
            System.out.println("Poof! The temperature is " + answer + "C");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered the temperature wrong!");
        }

        if (temperature.contains("F")) {
            temperature = temperature.replace(f , ' ');
            temp = Double.valueOf(temperature);
            answer = temp - 30 / 2;
            System.out.println("Poof! The temperature is " + answer + "C");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered the temperature wrong!");
        }

        if (temperature.contains("C")) {
            temperature = temperature.replace(c , ' ');
            temp = Double.valueOf(temperature);
            answer = temp + 30 * 2;
            System.out.println("Poof! The temperature is " + answer + "F");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered the temperature wrong!");
        }

        if (temperature.contains("c")) {
            temperature = temperature.replace(c , ' ');
            temp = Double.valueOf(temperature);
            answer = temp + 30 * 2;
            System.out.println("Poof! The temperature is " + answer + "F");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered the temperature wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I reckon you need f='F' rather than 'f'.

Comment: use `String.toLowercase()` or `String.toUppercase()` on `temperture` if you don't want to check against both cases

Comment: @vandale it is within code that checks for stuff like `if (temperature.contains("F")) `

Comment: @user2310289 yes, but if he doesn't want to check for both "C" and "c" like he does, then he can convert the case and shorten his code (he appears to only check for "F" though)

Answer (score 1):

you can not convert 69C to a number can you.  The replace is case sensitive

try

```
temperature = temperature.replace('C' , ' ');
```

of course you can change your varaable to 'C'

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you everything you need to know - right down to the line number!. "69C" is not an integer, so when you try to parse it, it doesn't work!.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this works fine when you are trying to convert f to c. You just cant do c to f.